# SDL_TTF Drawing int to string memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, drawing, sdl, sdl-ttf

Alright so I have been trying to display an integer that is able to update and reflect that on screen. (e.x. Displaying the x and y coordinates for the mouse position), and it ran just how I wanted, but then I opened the good ol'task manager and saw that I had reached around 600mb after running for 7 minutes. When I commented out the integers that I rendered on screen(so that they would not draw or update). The program hovered around 20mb after 7 mins. I have been unsuccessful in finding the problem, can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong? Thanks.

//TextMangager.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TEXTMANAGER_H
#define TEXTMANAGER_H

#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include "graphicsManager.h"
#include <sstream>

struct textManager{
public:
    textManager(){}
    ~textManager();
    void SetText(std::string msg, int x, int y);
    void draw();
    void setFont(std::string filepath, int size);
    void changeFontSize(int size);
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
    void setColor(int r, int g, int b);
    void intToString(Uint32 number, int x, int y);

private:
    TTF_Font*font;
    SDL_Texture*texture;
    SDL_Rect dst;
    SDL_Rect src;
    SDL_Surface*surface;
    SDL_Color color;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string text;


};

#endif // TEXTMANAGER_H
```

//Part of TextManager.cpp

```
    void textManager::intToString(Uint32 number, int x, int y)
{
    ss << number;
    text = ss.str().c_str();
    surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, text.c_str(), color);
    if (surface == NULL)
        cout << "surface is NULL \n" << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Gfx::Instance()->getRenderer(), surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    src.x = 0;
    src.y = 0;
    src.w = dst.w = surface->w;
    src.h = dst.h = surface->h;
    dst.x = x;
    dst.y = y;

    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &src.w, &src.h);
    ss.str(std::string().c_str());

}

void textManager::draw()
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(Gfx::Instance()->getRenderer(), texture, &src, &dst);
}


textManager::~textManager()
{
    if (texture != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    font = NULL;
    surface = NULL;
    ss.clear();
    delete surface;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `textManager::intToString` you create a surface with `TTF_RenderText_Blended` and then create a texture from that surface.

You are freeing the surface but it looks like you aren't doing the same for the texture. This means every frame the texture point will be re-assigned but the memory will not be free'd up resulting in a continual memory leak.